# How to receive a list in Node.js from Flutter using a single API call to be stored in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, flutter, dart, mongoose

I am new to Node.js, and I need help with my project. I am using Flutter as my android application, a Node.js as my back-end, a Heroku as my API services, and a MongoDB as my database. The problem is, let's say I have 30 objects in a list of Flutter, how can I implement a code in Node.js to receive a whole list in a single API call?

So far I have implemented Node.js to receive the objects one by one, but, calling API back to back for 30 times is not very practical I would say. The list is a heart rate data for an exercise.

MongoDB. I want to store heart rate data in **heartrateAerobicList**:

```
{
    "_id":{"$oid":"fdfg"},
    "uniqueId":{"$numberInt":"1122"},
    "name":"Jacob",
    "objectives":[],
    "completed_aerobic_exercise":[
        {
            "type":"Senaman Aerobik",
            "exerciseId":"#52333",
            "dateStart":"2022-08-03 18:09:51.073324",
            "dateCompleted":"2022-08-03 18:12:02.831211",
            "heartrateAerobicList":[
                {
                    "value":{"$numberInt":"6"},
                    "date":"2022-08-03 18:09:51.073324"
                },
                {
                    "value":{"$numberInt":"11"},
                    "date":"2022-08-03 18:09:51.073324"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My back-end Node.js so far that receives the objects in the list one by one. This is the part I have a problem where I do not know how to receive a whole list in a single API call to be saved in the database:

```
//Update new heartrate data of an aerobic exercise
routes.post('/api/insert-aerobic-heartrate', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await User.findOneAndUpdate(
            {
                uniqueId: parseInt(req.body.uniqueId),
                "completed_aerobic_exercise.exerciseId": req.body.exerciseId,
            }, 
            {
                $push: {
                    "completed_aerobic_exercise.$.heartrateAerobicList": {
                        value: parseInt(req.body.value),
                        date: req.body.date,
                    },
                }
            },
        )
        res.send("complete enter heartrate for aerobic");
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log("An error occurred " + error.message)
    }
});
```

My API call in Flutter using HTTP packages:

```
var url2 = Uri.parse('https://dummy.herokuapp.com/api/insert-aerobic-heartrate'); //link is a dummy
var response2 = await http.post(url2,
    body:
    {
        "uniqueId": "${widget.userId}",
        "exerciseId": widget.exeID,
        "value": "12",
        "date": "2022-08-03 18:09:51.073324"
    });
```

I hope I have provided all the necessary information for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Send the whole list in POST request

```dart
var url2 = Uri.parse('https://dummy.herokuapp.com/api/insert-aerobic-heartrate'); //link is a dummy
var response2 = await http.post(url2,
    body:
    {
        "uniqueId": "${widget.userId}",
        "exerciseId": widget.exeID, 
        "values": [

{"value": "12",
        "date": "2022-08-03 18:09:51.073324"}, 
{
"value": "13",
        "date": "2022-08-03 18:09:52"}, 
//....
]
            
    });
```

On the backend change the place where you push a single object

```js
$push: {
                    "completed_aerobic_exercise.$.heartrateAerobicList": {
                        value: parseInt(req.body.value),
                        date: req.body.date,
                    },
                }
```

with the list which you received in the request

```js
var values = req.body.values.map((x) => {
value: parseInt(x.value),
                        date: x.date
});
```

Sorry, I do not know how to add array into array in MongoDB, but I believe you should use `$each` operator for it, pls check https://codeforgeek.com/each-operator-in-mongodb/